# Winforms Datagridview row selection isssue

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am doing a function like I have a `DataGridView` in my `UserControl`, and it is hosted in Base Form. This `Grid` has 3 columns such as ID, Name, Age and this Age column is a `ComboBox` control. When the application starts, the `Grid` is populated with data from the database table Students. The selection mode is single Row wise. At first, it will show IDs and Names, but the Age column is empty, and the user can click on that column - which is a `ComboBox` control.

Suppose that the user populated data stems from the DB, and there are only 10 rows. The User clicks on the 4th row and tries to specify a value from the `ComboBox`. Fine, that is ok. Now see that the current row is 4th and that row is selected. Then the user tries to click on the 6th row. But it suddenly selects the very first row [0 index]. I clicked on 6th row, but it is not selecting the 6th row. Instead, the very first row is selected automatically.

The `dgv_RowEnter` is the first event that is fired when we clicked on the row. But there is another event that is invoking before the `dgv_RowEnter` event that I don't know.

Which is that event?

First, I select a row and picked a number from a `ComboBox` [Age Column] and after that, when I click on any other row - at that time it is selecting [highlighting] the very first row [0th rowindex].

How to prevent this ?

Comment: Code that reproduces the problem usually helps.

Comment: My guess would be to change the `EditMode` to `EditOnEnter`.

Comment: @LarsTech It is already in EditOnEnter. Anyother way ??

Comment: You're making me guess.  Post code that reproduces the problem and your audience can better help you.

Comment: I am not following what you mean by… _”How to select the 6th or 3rd or 7th or any row when user clicks on other rows.”_ … ? … In other words... "why" would you want to do this?

Comment: I guess there will be a property to select full row did you tried that `DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect`

Answer (score 1):

In your post, you ask:

> The dgv_RowEnter is the first event that is fired when we clicked on the row. But there is another event that is invoking before the dgv_RowEnter event that I don't know. **Which is that event?**

The question you're asking indicates that the default behavior of `DataGridView` is not providing the events you want in the order you want them.   Using data binding with the `DataSource` property is the fastest way to make DGV behave in a decent manner out of the box and that would be my first suggestion. But it sounds as though you are interacting with the DGV directly which implies that you are an advanced user who wants to be "at the front of the line" for the events that DGV is sending. The way to intercept `SelectedRow`, `SelectedColumn`, and `SelectedCell` before they go out as events is to make a `CustomDataGridView : DataGridView` and override the `SetSelectedRowCore`, `SetSelectedColumnCore`, and `SetSelectedCellCore` methods respectively.

You will need to change two lines in the Form.Designer.cs file:

```
// private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;
private CustomDataGridView dataGridView1;
```

and:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    // this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
    this.dataGridView1 = new CustomDataGridView();
    .
    .
    .
}
```

The console output shown below demonstrates that the custom class as shown is now a "first responder" when these states occur.

```
class CustomDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    protected override void SetSelectedRowCore(
        int rowIndex, 
        bool selected)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name} Row {rowIndex}");
        base.SetSelectedRowCore(rowIndex, selected);
    }
    protected override void SetSelectedCellCore(
        int columnIndex, 
        int rowIndex, 
        bool selected)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name} Column {columnIndex} Row {rowIndex}");
        base.SetSelectedCellCore(columnIndex, rowIndex, selected);
    }
    protected override void SetSelectedColumnCore(
        int columnIndex, 
        bool selected)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name} Column {columnIndex}");
        base.SetSelectedColumnCore(columnIndex, selected);
    }
    protected override bool SetCurrentCellAddressCore(
        int columnIndex, 
        int rowIndex, 
        bool setAnchorCellAddress, 
        bool validateCurrentCell, 
        bool throughMouseClick)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name} Column {columnIndex} Row {rowIndex}");
        return base.SetCurrentCellAddressCore(
            columnIndex, 
            rowIndex, 
            setAnchorCellAddress, 
            validateCurrentCell, 
            throughMouseClick);
    }
}
```

[image: event log]